# Is it possible to download an older version of XCode?

Tags: xcode

I don't develop in XCode very often, and recently MacPorts told me I needed to get 3.1 in order for a package to work. I went to apple, and they offered me the latest version, which turns out only to work for OSX 6. Since I have OSX 5, it doesn't help me any. Is there any way to get xcode 3.1.* from apple at this point?

Comment: It's difficult to google for because it's hard to search for leopard without getting snow leopard results...

Comment: Yes, sometimes that gives results...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Developer Tools section on [connect.apple.com](http://connect.apple.com/) has download links for several older XCode versions, including the 3.1.x ones. You'll need a (free) ADC account.

Comment: Thanks! I had been to that page multiple times, but I guess I never quite found the "developer tools" section until you expressly pointed it out. I'll accept this answer when the system lets me. Hooray stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

## Xcode 3

- [xcode 3.2.3 and ios sdk 4.0.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_sdk_4.0.1__final/xcode_3.2.3_and_ios_sdk_4.0.1.dmg)
- [xcode 3.2.3 and ios sdk 4.0.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_sdk_4.0.2__final/xcode_3.2.3_and_ios_sdk_4.0.2.dmg)
- [xcode 3.2.4 and ios sdk 4.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_sdk_4.1__final/xcode_3.2.4_and_ios_sdk_4.1.dmg)
- [xcode 3.2.5 and ios sdk 4.2 final](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_sdk_4.2__final/xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg)
- [xcode 3.2.6 and ios sdk 4.3](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg)

## Xcode 4

- [xcode 4 and ios sdk 4.3 GM](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_4_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final.dmg)
- [xcode 4.0.1 and ios sdk 4.3](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.0.1_and_ios_sdk_4.3/xcode_4.0.1_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg)
- [xcode 4.0.2 and ios sdk 4.3](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.0.2_and_ios_sdk_4.3/xcode_4.0.2_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg)
- [xcode 4.1 for snow leopard](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard_21110/xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard.dmg)