# where can i download iphone sdk 3.x with xcode

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I was wondering if there is a place where i could get the earlier version (archives etc) for iphone SDK.There are certain times when one needs to play with the 3.x SDK.Can anyone please guide me for this.Thanks

Comment: Does it comes under development part?

Comment: When do you think you need this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I download the older iPhone OS 3.1 SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786601/where-can-i-download-the-older-iphone-os-3-1-sdk)

Comment: See also [Is it possible to download an older version of XCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630342/is-it-possible-to-download-an-older-version-of-xcode)

Answer (score 2):

download latest sdk. set deploy target to 3.0 and don't use new features that added after 3.0 so it should runs well on your 3.0 devices.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Apple provides the old tools. I archive all of the developer tools as they are released.